# Using C# linq, How can i group by specific item in array?

Tags: c#, linq, collections, group-by

I have an array of Project objects.

```
IEnumerable<Project> projects = GetProjects();
```

Each Project has a property called "Applications" which is an array of strings.

```
IEnumerable<string> applicationsForProject = project.Applications();
```

Some projects have 1 application (1 element in the array) but others have many.

I want to group all of my projects by individual application so I can generate a view that looks like this:

- App 1: 10 projects
- App 2: 4 projects
- App 3: 5 projects

If i do this:

```
var projectsByApp = projects.GroupBy(r=>r.Applications);
```

that will group not by the distinct applications but by the list so I wind up getting duplicate rows in my view (since project 1 might have App1 and App 2 and project 2 might just have App 2)

Is there any better way to group by distinct application name across the array of projects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var projectsByApp = projects.SelectMany(p => p.Applications
                                              .Select(a => new { p, a }))
                            .GroupBy(x => x.a)
                            .Select(g => new {
                                            Application = g.Key,
                                            Projects = g.Select(x => p).ToList())
                                         })
                            .ToList();
```

Or even simpler to read:

```
var projectsByApp = (from p in projects
                     from a in p.Applications
                     group p by a into g
                     select new {
                         Application= g.Key,
                         Projects = g.ToList()
                     }).ToList();
```

Both queries return a list of anonymous type objects with two properties: `Application` typed as `Application` and `Projects` as `List<Project>`